# Expanded and Swipe-able cell in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `TableView`, where users can click and expand each cell (UI: [click](http://i-fotki.info/22/8bd7adec1d22493f52f177373b5ffe4f059fe5285019588.png.html)). This is the code for that (also I created `.xib` file to layout this cell):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating  {
 var selectedIndex: IndexPath?
    var isExpended = false

    func didExpandCell() {
        self.isExpended = !isExpended
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndex!], with: .automatic)

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "wordCell", for: indexPath) as! CellController
        if searchController.isActive {
            cell.word.text = filtered[indexPath.row].word
            cell.translation.text = filtered[indexPath.row].translation
            cell.date.text = filtered[indexPath.row].fullDate
            cell.exOne.text = filtered[indexPath.row].exOne
            cell.exTwo.text = filtered[indexPath.row].exTwo
        } else {
            cell.word.text = words[indexPath.row].word
            cell.translation.text = words[indexPath.row].translation
            cell.date.text = words[indexPath.row].fullDate
            cell.exOne.text = words[indexPath.row].exOne
            cell.exTwo.text = words[indexPath.row].exTwo
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath
        self.didExpandCell()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if isExpended && self.selectedIndex == indexPath {
            return 180
        }
        return 70
    }
}
```

Also, all Cells are swipe-able. This is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { action, index in
            print("Edit")
        }
        edit.backgroundColor = .blue

        let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
            print("Delete")
        }
        delete.backgroundColor = .red

        return [delete, edit]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

**The problem:**

When I swipe Cell, it always expends in a half, this is my UI after swiping: [click](http://i-fotki.info/22/c5e3b90c0acf6b23415cb04f58ba960e059fe5285019588.png.html). Is it possible not to expand Cell if I swipe them?

Comment: Can you put a debug point in didSelectRowAt method and see when you swipe , is this mehod called?

Comment: isn't your expand function improper, func didExpandCell() ? Say, if I click on Cell1, isExpended = true and it opens Cell. Again if I click on Cell2, it will set isExpended = false and not expand Cell2.

Comment: No, it isn't called on swipe

Comment: Hm, it seems like you are right, haven't mentioned this before. How can I improve that btw?

Comment: Can you put a debug point in heightForRowAt method and check if its called when you swipe? I have made a dummy project it does not cause problem

Comment: With debug point It throws me an error when I load my ViewController... Stops at self.tableView.reloadData() in my ViewDidLoad()

Comment: Ok initially let the app run without any debug point and then right before swipe go to heightForRowAt method and add debug point, and see if this method is called

Comment: No, this method also isn't called

Comment: Every time you swipe the cell, it is expanded or it happens sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, but the problem was that I haven't set constraints for expanded version of the cell. That's why this labels were moving with swipe menu. Now it works.
Thank you for all your replies!